# "Submit" button does not appear while applying for expedited app review

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Due to some reason I have to send my app to Expedited review.
For this first of all, I have submitted my app successfully on itunes connect.

Currently my application is in "Waiting for Review" state.

Now I am applying for expedited review. See the following screenshot.[image]

but on this page I am not able to find "Submit" button to send the request to apple review team. Anyone knows how to submit app for expedited review?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I refreshed it twice but not able to get button

Comment: some times wait and check bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is a bug of Mozilla.

I open developer account in Mozilla version 38.0.5 and in this version form for expedite review does not open.

In other browser(e.g, chrome, safari) it works fine.